# HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath missing last tag in result

Tags: perl, xpath, mechanize, html-treebuilder

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize;
my $tree = new HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
my $url = "http://www.elaws.gov.bw/wondersbtree.php";
$mech->get($url);
$tree->parse($mech->content());
@nodes = $tree->findnodes("//p[font = 'PRINCIPAL LEGISLATION']");
print @nodes[0]->as_HTML;
```

The above code prints out the HTML element searched for, but it is missing the final `</p>` tag.  Why?  Is this intentional or is it a bug in the module?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the [`as_HTML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element#as_HTML) method omits certain optional end tags:

> **as_HTML**
>
> ```
> $s = $h->as_HTML();
> $s = $h->as_HTML($entities);
> $s = $h->as_HTML($entities, $indent_char);
> $s = $h->as_HTML($entities, $indent_char, \%optional_end_tags);
> ```
>
> [ ... ]
>
> If `\%optional_end_tags` is specified and defined, it should be a reference to a hash that holds a true value for every tag name whose end tag is optional. Defaults to `\%HTML::Element::optionalEndTag`, which is an alias to `%HTML::Tagset::optionalEndTag`, which, at time of writing, contains true values for `p, li, dt, dd`. A useful value to pass is an empty hashref, `{}`, which means that no end-tags are optional for this dump.

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content('<p>foo</p>');
my @nodes = $tree->findnodes('//p');

say $nodes[0]->as_HTML(undef, undef, {});
```

Output:

```
<p>foo</p>
```

Note that you should always `use strict;` and `use warnings 'all';`.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, the end tag is optional for [P elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1).

Comment: The original HTML source does include the end tag.